# How to deal with server throughput quota programatically?

Tags: google-api, throughput, quota, google-search-console

I have a program that make many queries to [Google Search Analytics](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics) server. My program does the queries one after the other sequentially, so each instant, only one query will be in process.

Google has advised about a throughput limit of 2000 queries per each 100 seconds at most so to configure my system to be the more efficient it could be I have two ideas on mind:

1. Known that 2000 queries per 100 seconds is one query per each 0.05 seconds, i have separated my queries by sleeping the process, but only if any query take less than 0.05 seconds, so the time the process will sleep in that case is the remaining time to complete the 0.05 second interval. If the query takes 0.05s or more I trigger the following without waiting.
2. The second idea is more easy to implement but I think it will be less efficient: i will trigger the queries taking note of the time when the process start so if i reach 2000 queries before 100 seconds, I will wait the remaining time sleeping.

So far I don't know how to measure which one is the best.

Which is your opinion about the two options? Any of them is better and why? Any additional option I haven't figured out? (specially if it's better than mine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you need to consider is that its 2000 requests per 100 seconds.  But you could do all 2000 requests in 10 seconds and still be on the good side of the quota.

I am curious as to why you are worried about it though.  If you get one of the following errors

- 403   userRateLimitExceeded
- 403   rateLimitExceeded
- 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED

Google just recommends that you implement [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) which consists of making your request getting the error sleeping for a bit and trying again.  (do this up to eight times).  Google will not penalize you for getting these errors they just ask that you wait a bit before trying again.

If you want to go crazy you can do something like what i did in my C# application I created a request queue that i use to track how much time has gone since i created the last 100 request.  I call it [Google APIs Flood Buster](http://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/).

Basically i have a queue where i log each requests as i make it before i make a new request i check how long it has gone since i started. Yes this requires moving the items around the queue a bit.  If there has gone more then 90 seconds then i sleep (100 - time since )  this has reduced my errors a great deal.  Its not perfect but that's because google is not perfect with regard to tracking your quota.  they are normally off by a little.

Comment: Wonderful question, directly in the target, you can't be more specific. 403 userRateLimitExceeded was the error I've dealing with and I haven't noticed about the recommended algorithm to manage it. Definitely I will take that solution (and thanks for the link of your project as I will have more than one look to it)